# How does Go slice capacity change on append?

Tags: go, slice

Running the example [The Go Tour](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/15) on server (currently on version 1.12.7), I find the capacity of slice doubling to the next power of 2, if the new slice length is larger than current backing array's length.

If I run the same program on my machine (version 1.10.3 on windows), the slice capacity changes to next multiple of two.

Why are they different? Is it because of Go version or run-time implementations? Is the capacity change deterministic?

The output on remote server is this

```
len=0 cap=0 []
len=1 cap=2 [0]
len=2 cap=2 [0 1]
len=5 cap=8 [0 1 2 3 4]
```

The output on local machine is this

```
len=0 cap=0 []
len=1 cap=1 [0]
len=2 cap=2 [0 1]
len=5 cap=6 [0 1 2 3 4]
```

This is the code for reference

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var s []int
    printSlice(s)

    // append works on nil slices.
    s = append(s, 0)
    printSlice(s)

    // The slice grows as needed.
    s = append(s, 1)
    printSlice(s)

    // We can add more than one element at a time.
    s = append(s, 2, 3, 4)
    printSlice(s)
}

func printSlice(s []int) {
    fmt.Printf("len=%d cap=%d %v\n", len(s), cap(s), s)
}
```

Comment: Can you share the output capacities in both the cases.

Comment: The implementation is [here](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/34778e58b30a3d615502a9f75bb603d6a13e0504/src/runtime/slice.go#L76).  An application should not rely on how the capacity is increased.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*TL;DR: It depends on the size of the elements stored in the array*

The implementation can be seen here:

https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/slice.go

But as you can see looking into the history it can't be relied to stay the same over time.

That might also explain the difference you may note on different versions of Go.

Making some tests show how a 0-size struct will increment capacity by just 1 element, and int or string will duplicate on each growth, and a 3-byte struct "roughly" doubles on each growth.

You can execute code like this using different types to see these different cases in action:

```
arr := []struct{}{}
oldCap := 0
for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
    arr = append(arr, struct{}{})
    if cap(arr) != oldCap {
        oldCap = cap(arr)
        fmt.Println("arr", cap(arr))
    }
}
```

Playground showing the cases described above:

https://play.golang.org/p/OKtCFskbp2t

Answer (score -1):

According to information from [Go slice internal](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals) The implementation behaviour of append is as follows.

It is just a multiple of the `(len(source slice) + len(new data)) * 2`

```
func AppendByte(slice []byte, data ...byte) []byte {
    m := len(slice)
    n := m + len(data)
    if n > cap(slice) { // if necessary, reallocate
        // allocate double what's needed, for future growth.
        newSlice := make([]byte, (n+1)*2)
        copy(newSlice, slice)
        slice = newSlice
    }
    slice = slice[0:n]
    copy(slice[m:n], data)
    return slice
}
```

Comment: No, it is just an example of self-implemented "append()" function. It can be used when you don't want to rely on internal Go implementation. But built-in append() behavior is not the same. @eugenioy's answer is correct.