# 2024 golang a slice of length 2 append 3 more elements, why does it have length 5 capacity 6 instead of capacity 5?

Tags: go, slice

https://go.dev/tour/moretypes/15

in this go tour tutorial, it is not explained why after each append, length and capacity are the same until the last one, where length is 5 and capacity is somehow 6? why is it different then any other append before it?

this is the output after running the sample code

```
len=0 cap=0 []
len=1 cap=1 [0]
len=2 cap=2 [0 1]
len=5 cap=6 [0 1 2 3 4]
```

Can you explain based on current version of go as of 2024-03-19 [How does Go slice capacity change on append?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57100525/how-does-go-slice-capacity-change-on-append)
as this question suggest, it is dependent on versions of go as of 2019, have this behavior changed in 2024 version of go ?

in a similar question from 10 years ago [How the slice is enlarged by append? Is the capacity always doubled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23531737/how-the-slice-is-enlarged-by-append-is-the-capacity-always-doubled)

*As of 2014-2020 the implemented rules are:*

it has been updated until 2020, a lot could have changed in golang since last 4 years, I feel like it is a valid question to revisit it since a decade ago and not a duplicate, as one of the answer literally says

> But as you can see looking into the history it can't be relied to stay
> the same over time.

Comment: There is a reason implementation specific questions are closed as off-topic, they are quickly outdated like what you're pointing out. The point is that the behavior is not specified other than capacity will be sufficient, and you don't need to know exactly what the implementation is to use `append`. If you need an exact capacity, then you set that exact capacity. If you want to know how it works out of curiosity, then you can look directly at the implementation.

Comment: if the question is closed as off topic then what you said would make sense, but it is closed as a duplicate, wouldn't the "original question" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57100525 be considered as off topics as well if that was true?  I don't think it is a good practice to tell people "just look at the implementation" if so these https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801008 questions would not exist as you can look them right up in the go doc, but none the less they make sof great for beginners as source code/documentation some times doesn't paint the whole picture

Comment: StackOverflow is not meant to be up-to-date documentation on a particular language implementation. Some of the answers exist, because they explain the language feature, and happen to add some implementation detail even if it wasn't necessary. Just because there are existing examples of answers which are not well suited to the site does not mean we want to add more

Comment: This is an implementation detail, but the short answer is that a heuristic is used that attempts to minimize reallocations, since they are expensive, without wasting a lot of space.

Comment: Also, because it's an implementation detail, and not part of the language spec, it is subject to change at any time and different Go compilers can use different heuristics for setting the capacity.